# Increasing voltage maximum value from 10 mv to 5v

Tags: adc

Since microcontrollers usually don’t have specific ports for measuring currents, but they do have ADC channels through which you can measure analog voltages of a certain range. This means a dc current can be indirectly measured by a microcontroller’s ADC channel by converting the current into voltage by placeing a resistance in series with the current path and measure the voltage drop across it.
My current range is from 0A to 10A , I have chosen 0,02ohm as a shunt resistance so my voltage will be in the range of 0 to 10mV.However, I need to increase this range to a maximum 5V to be measured by the microcontroller 
How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

A solution is to amplify the 0 to 10 mV using an opamp circuit, here's an example: [image]

I would also increase the value of the shunt resistor though, 10 mV full range is not much. 100 mV would give you more immunity to noise and other disturbances. The power dissipation in the shunt resistor will increase though.

Another solution could be a small module like [this sensor](http://www.ebay.nl/itm/New-design-20A-range-Current-Sensor-Module-ACS712-Module-Arduino-module-Y3-/261913749632?hash=item3cfb46a880)
it has an the added benefit, the side where the current flows is isolated from the part which you need to connect to the ADC. Check the specification if the accuracy is good enough for your purpose !

Comment: What I am really trying to do, read the current and the voltage of my photovoltaic module under dark condition and send this tow values to a microcontroller to be able to plot the IV curve.so the problem to measure the current its almost solved but to measure the voltage I need a voltage divider to get a range of 5V since my output range from PV is 100V . Can I use ready module to reduce the range instead of building up my own voltage divider ???

Comment: @KhoulodGhanem - just be aware (from the data sheet) that your zero reading can be off by as much as +/- 0.3 amps for a 20 amp unit.

Comment: A voltage divider consists of 2 resistors, you don't really need a module for that.

Comment: I didnt get you ??? what do you mean by "zero reading can be off by as much as +/- 0.3 amps for a 20 amp unit " my English is not so perfect besides I dont have an experience with electronics

Comment: It means that although 0 A (zero current) is flowing, the sensor can read out anything between -0.3 A to 0.3 A instead of 0 A. This is called offset. It means that small currents are not measured so accurately.